# Show and hide a frame using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide the frame "topFrame" and "menu" when I click on any image or button and unhide it when I click on it again. Is there a way I can achieve it easily?

Sorry for not posting "topFrame" and "menu" jsp files, as those are dynamically rendering in my application.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>


        <frameset rows="80,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
            <frame src="/someAction1.do" name="topFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="">

            <frameset cols="20%,80%*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
                <frame src="/someAction2.do" name="menu" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="true" scrolling="auto" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
                <frame src="/someAction2.do" name="information" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
            </frameset>

        </frameset>

        <noframes>
            // ...
        </noframes>

</html>
```

Comment: @pc-shooter, sorry I didn't get you. If your concern is regarding still using framesets. Then I'll say its the requirement in my running application. And I can't change that code. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code at the bottom of your page before the `body` closing tag:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        $('img, button').on("click" , function (e) {
            $('frame[name="topFrame"], frame[name="menu"]').toggle();
        });
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Here I have one question in which file I have to add this code as you can see there is no body tag in my current framesets containing HTML file.

Comment: just add it before </html> tag

Comment: </frameset>
    <noframes>
    //....
    </noframes>
<script>
(function(){
    $('img, button').on("click" , function (e) {
        $('frame[name="topFrame"], frame[name="menu"]').toggle();
    });
}());
</script>
    </html>
I've added this script in the end of file, But its not working. :(

Comment: I have started new thread to make my problem more clearly. Please refer this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030228/completely-hide-frame-in-framesets-using-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** function to show/hide.

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('frame[name="topFrame"],frame[name="menu"]').toggle();
});
```

If the buttons too are generated dynamically, delegation would be important.

```
$(document).on('click','button_or_img',function(){
    $('frame[name="topFrame"],frame[name="menu"]').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Here I come know about how to select frame with name attribute.

Comment: Glad to help there. Goodluck.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following would help you. The code is very simple and self explanatory...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function show1()
            {
                document.getElementById("div_main").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            function close_dialog()
            {
                document.getElementById("div_main").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            *
            {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            #div_main
            {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.8);
                z-index:300;
                position:fixed;
                visibility:hidden;
            }
            #cls_btn
            {
                height:100px;
                width:100px;
                margin-left:50%;
            }
            body
            {
                background-color:#09F;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div_main">
            <input type="button" value="Close Me" onClick="close_dialog()" id="cls_btn">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="show1()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('[name="menu"]').toggle();
    $('[name="information"]').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via fadeToggle()/toggle().

```
$('img, button').click(function () {
    $('frame[name="topFrame"], frame[name="menu"]').fadeToggle("slow");
});
```